# Magento Community - Hosting :: Need Advice which sharing hosting will run magento fast

Tags: web-hosting, shared-hosting, zend-framework, magento, virtual-hosting

Need Advice which sharing hosting  will run **Magento Community** fast or some other not expensive solution.

This website will not have a lot of users, 
I only need that it will run fast for 100-20 users in same time.
The problem with magento is database design that make this system very slow , also other staff not the best.

I had hostmonster.com and justhost.com for previous website but it wasn't fast enough for single user that not located in USA (my customer areas: Asia, Africa).
each action that involve database takes a lot of time.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way for you to address this is to find a cheap vps.
replace the setup with nginx, php-fpm & some memcached distributed caching.

This will provide the best utilization of the resources available for your shop.

Or find a dedicated magento hosting provider that already has an optimized magento infrastructure.

Comment: do you know some real magento website with a lot products that run fast?according database design of magento - he should work very slow.ple

Comment: There are sites running with 1.1 million SKU's Others are doing yearly Billion USD / Year in revenue. www.nordstrom.com is one.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't suggest a VPS in place of shared hosting, for a number of reasons.

Let's assume your budget is £30 per month - from bytemark.co.uk this gives you

1. 1000MB RAM
2. 1 CPU Core
3. 20GB storage

The downsides of using a VPS being

1. You need to manage your own server. That means you have to optimise the server, monitor the server, fix any issues with the server - *have you got that level of experience?*
2. Your I/O is shared. Anyone else's activity using the common HDDs will bottleneck *anything* your Magento store needs to do
3. You are limited to 1GB RAM, to put this into perspective ...

Each PHP thread (visitor) needs an average 30MB RAM and its corresponding MySQL connection will need just a bit more. So that is 80MB per visitor. Your base OS needs about 140MB RAM to run. MySQL base wants as much as possible, but as a minimum, it will need 300MB.

So you are using 440MB, leaving you support for 7 active visitors - which is fortunate, because 1 2.5GHz core can push through a maximum of 7 requests per second (for Magento).

--

Conversely, you could pick a Magento host that already optimises its shared servers, uses external DB servers, and usually has a powerful machine that you can burst resources on, to a factor of around 8 of what your VPS offers.

There are a few Magento hosting comparison sites out there that will help you make this decision.

1. www.magentobenchmark.com
2. www.magespeedtest.com

Comment: Great stats on VPS!  I think this explains why the waiting time spikes on my website when I rapidly hit it.